# Advice and ideas regarding the development of and editor similar the the PlayCanvas web editor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, typescript, web

I've been looking at the PlayCanvas web based editor. It's a obviously based on the Unity GUI but it's developed using web technology.

As a a seasoned Developer I could quite easily start coding in earnest to produce something similar. However, I was wondering if I should code a similar application from scratch or if there are any frameworks or libraries out there that people would suggest that I could use ease the burden?

I'm aware Of React and Angular although I've never used them.

Should I use these? Or any other frameworks or libraries out there?

Have any of you developed something similar and if so, how did you approach it?

Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I like AngularJs.  React is also popular, but I feel Angular offers quite a bit more.  I have a basic Angular setup somewhere and I can share it with you if you are interested.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions asking to recommend books, libraries etc. are considered off topic. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: frameworks are good when a business needs a small app on a deadline, they aren't that great for powerful or complex apps since the overhead and limits tend to snowball and you're left spending more time digging through framework docs and plugin hunting than you are writing code. just my $0.02...